# WebDriver - headless issue

Tags: webdriver

I need to automate this following website:
https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/web/wyszukiwarka-krs/strona-glowna/index.html

When I work on my automation in my testing environment then all is fine, but in test I use "visible" normal mode.

But on enduser PC this should be run in headless mode, so I checked my code and I notice that with headless mode this website returns: `The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator`

**Any concept why this issue occurs and how to solve this problem?**

Thank you in advance

I also have this following information get back from WebDriver:

> Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45
> (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947})
> on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully.
>
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:63205/devtools/browser/ffacc4cb-af7c-4157-881d-a8c7db522d30
> [1206/145642.826:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)]
> ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send
> GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer. [1206/145645.262:INFO:CONSOLE(402)]
> "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or
> created) after a user gesture on the page.
> https://...........goo.gl/7K7WLu", source:
> https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/08c5699bd4ab2000035ad69152344c2a5571187707e8019758fff5530615875b3778567088bde213?type=11
> (402) [1206/145645.263:INFO:CONSOLE(402)] "The ScriptProcessorNode is
> deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead.
> (https://.........bit.ly/audio-worklet)", source:
> https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/08c5699bd4ab2000035ad69152344c2a5571187707e8019758fff5530615875b3778567088bde213?type=11
> (402) [1206/145645.264:INFO:CONSOLE(405)] "The AudioContext was not
> allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture
> on the page. https://...........goo.gl/7K7WLu", source:
> https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/08c5699bd4ab2000035ad69152344c2a5571187707e8019758fff5530615875b3778567088bde213?type=11
> (405) [1206/145645.265:INFO:CONSOLE(408)] "The AudioContext was not
> allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture
> on the page. https://...........goo.gl/7K7WLu", source:
> https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/08c5699bd4ab2000035ad69152344c2a5571187707e8019758fff5530615875b3778567088bde213?type=11
> (408) [1206/145645.265:ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(228)]
> WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
> [1206/145645.265:ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(228)]
> WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
> [1206/145645.306:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(318)] [.WebGL-0000249C00081B00]GL
> Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU
> stall due to ReadPixels [1206/145645.467:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(318)]
> [.WebGL-0000249C00081B00]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance,
> GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
> [1206/145645.564:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(318)] [.WebGL-0000249C00081B00]GL
> Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU
> stall due to ReadPixels [1206/145645.652:INFO:CONSOLE(0)]
> "[.WebGL-0000249C00081B00]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance,
> GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels", source:
> https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/?type=20 (0)
> [1206/145645.652:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-0000249C00081B00]GL Driver
> Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due
> to ReadPixels", source: https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/?type=20 (0)
> [1206/145645.654:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-0000249C00081B00]GL Driver
> Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due
> to ReadPixels", source: https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/TSPD/?type=20 (0)

EDIT: 2021/12/08

Finally I find out that a had to add capability `user-agent` as `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36`. The interesting thing was that when I was used `60.0.3112.50` instead `96.0.4664.93` then my automation works well in `Headless` when it come to navigate to the desired wegsite, but stoped to work on even in `Normal` mode when it comes to using this website - I mean navigation to website works but after filling the form and submiting data I started to get the same issue `....consult administrator......`.

To clarify the matter:
Before I added args `user-agent` in `normal` mode works both navigate and search feature.

Before I added args `user-agent` with outdated `60.0.3112.50` setting, in `normal` mode works navigate but search stop working.

So now my question changes to:
**Why, with out-of-date settings in `user-agent` , the navigation to the page work properly, but the search on this page does not work? Could it just be related to the strange configuration, design of this site?**

Comment: I test it now on my laptop at home. The same code works well in headless mode. I must to check which version of GoogleChrome I have on both machines. And also which drivers are used on them.

Answer (score 3):

```
options.add_argument("disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

only these two lines are solution
and now it work perfect

Comment: Please leave the judging (including whether it is accepted as "solved" or at least as helpful) to the voters. Also please drop the "me too" aspects.